# Return row label for max value in excel r

Tags: excel

How do I return the value in a column being used to label the rows of a table? For example, given the table below I want to find MAX(A:A) and return "Three" instead of the value 1.

```
        |A      B      C    D
--------|---------------------------------
One     |0.2    0.2   0.5   0.4
Two     |0.1    0.1   0.6   0.1
Three   |1.0    0.3   0.7   0.2
Four    |0.5    0.4   0.5   0.3
```

Assume if two values are the same then returning either is acceptable.

Comment: What if more than one cell has 1 (or whatever the max is)?

Comment: What would be returned for "B" ?  What if there were two "1" under "A"?

Comment: For the sake of argument, the values will be mutually exclusive. For the actual table I have this is guaranteed. Although if identical values ever occurred then returning any of the acceptable values would be fine.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming data in rows 1 to 4, put this in B5 to get the answer for column B:

```
=INDEX(A1:A4,MATCH(MAX(B1:B4),B1:B4,0))
```

Comment: @mjm26 - To retrieve the row label identifying the MAX from B1:E4 see [INDEX MATCH value from matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34289316/index-match-value-from-matrix/34291159#34291159).

Answer (score 2):

use the OFFSET and MATCH functions with MAX

OFFSET(A1,MATCH(MAX(A:A),A:A,0),0)

MATCH returns the position of a lookup value in the lookup array.