# Find which rows has longest Cell in a given column?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Currently I have a function in VBA that finds the longest cell length in a given column. it inserts a column next to whatever given column, inserts `LEN(A1)` (whatever the desired column address is) and fills that down, then It uses the `MAX` function to find the greatest value.

Until now that's been good enough but now the user wants to know which row that greatest value is on as well. is there a way to do that without sorting or filtering?

The function is run once by the user and loops across each column, and there are about 150000 rows, so it would take a while to filter / sort 15 times.

any suggestions appreciated

Comment: should it be VBA or formulas also avaliable?

Comment: Non-VBA solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929216/return-row-label-for-max-value-in-excel-r) might help.

Comment: either way works because if its non-vba I can just use VBA to insert the formula in a cell. I actually use many non-VBA solutions, in VBA :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=match(max(*column*),*column*,0) will give you the row number where the max occurs.

You could then use

=index(*othercolumn*,match(max(*column*),*column*,0)) to get some other column value for that row

Comment: Giving this one to you because the answer is much simpler, and it integrates with what already doing inserting a column and getting the lengths. instead of using just the max function now I can just tack your solution underneath :)

Comment: Yeh, but needs an additional column :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming values in A2:A6

This will give you row number, relative to the data range

```
=MATCH(MAX(LEN(A2:A6));LEN(A2:A6);0)
```

This will give row number relative to the worksheet

```
=ROW(A2)-ROW($A$1)+MATCH(MAX(LEN(A2:A6));LEN(A2:A6);0)
```

And this will give you the value

```
=INDEX(A2:A6;MATCH(MAX(LEN(A2:A6));LEN(A2:A6);0))
```

All those are array formulas, you need **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** to enter them

Comment: are those supposed to be semi colons or commas?

Comment: @user1759942 It depends on your language settings.

Comment: depends on your Regional Settings, for me is ";" for you, eventually is ",", so replace ";" by ","

Comment: I just get #VALUE? when I insert that formula. I put it in A7 with different words in a2 - a6...

Comment: Ctrl Shift Enter to enter the formula, it is an array formula  :)
I tried all formulas, they all work...

Comment: ah there we go. Thanks. Never used an array formula before.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to everyone who posted, I also found this formula: `=CELL("address",OFFSET(A1,MATCH(MAX(A1:A10),A1:A10,0)-1,0))` (assuming data is A1 - A10) which will give the cells actual address as well if anyone ever wants it. heres the site for that: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/139574