# INDEX MATCH value from matrix

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I am fine at using index match to pull a value from one column, but what I want to look up a value from a matrix?

I have a list of errors by area, so a row (RowA2:A6) for each area and a column (columns A:F) for each error type and then a count of errors by area.  I then use a max function to get the maximum value from the matrix.  I then want to look up which area is associated with this value.  However the value can come from A3 to F6.  Is there a way I can do index match over this matrix rather than just one column?

Comment: Do you mean *'a column (columns **B**:F) for each error type'*? How are the areas labeled? Perhaps you could supply some sample data together with expected results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enter number into a cell and search an array for that number using a 2D range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224403/enter-number-into-a-cell-and-search-an-array-for-that-number-using-a-2d-range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) can quickly locate the row or column containing the [MAX](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/max-function-f7bec1eb-9c66-489a-9166-51d2c9d19333) value from a two-dimensioned matrix and pass that back to an [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) of either the row or column header labels.

The formulas in E9:E10 are:

```
=INDEX(C2:G2, AGGREGATE(15, 6, COLUMN(A:E)/(C3:G6=MAX(C3:G6)), 1))
=INDEX(B3:B6, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(1:4)/(C3:G6=MAX(C3:G6)), 1))
```

[image: Return row label for max value in excel]

---

<sub>The conditional formatting rules that visually identify the maximum value and both column and row labels are:

    Red *Applies to* $C$3:$G$6, UAFTDWCTF, `=C3=MAX($C$3:$G$6)`

    Orange *Applies to* $B$3:$B$6, UAFTDWCTF, `=COUNTIF($C3:$G3, MAX($C$3:$G$6))`

    Orange *Applies to* $C$2:$G$2, UAFTDWCTF, `=COUNTIF(C$3:C$6, MAX($C$3:$G$6))`</sub>

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>